# "not only but also" or "do not only but also"

Tags: phrase-usage

1. He not only composes songs, but also performs them.
2. He doesn't only compose songs, but also performs them.
3. He doesn't only compose songs, but also perform them.

I know 1 is grammatically correct, but how about 2 and 3?  Are they correct or wrong?

Comment: **also** can be omitted in #1.   #2 seems marginal to me. #3 as Edmond Kirsch remarks has a verb-number issue.

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct. 3 is incorrect.  It should be "performs".